# How can I pass EditText value continuesly to extends WallpaperService

Tags: android, live, wallpaper

I am trying to build a live wallpaper and want to pass a **edittext** string to `wallpaperservice` from `MainActivity`. Is there any method to pass the **edittext** value at any time and it draw on the canvas.

this is my MainActiviy

```
 public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText et;
private Button setWall;
private TextView tv;
public String passString = "";

ConsoleWallpaper consol;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    consol = new ConsoleWallpaper();

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    setWall.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.setWall:

        break;

    }

}
```

}

and this is extends WallpaperService where i want to pass values every time on button click.

```
public class MyWallpaper extends WallpaperService {
public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "WallpaperSettings";
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();



public String receivedString= "";


private Canvas c;

MainActivity main = new MainActivy();

Handler testHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate() {



    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {


    return new TextEngine();
}

class TextEngine extends Engine implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private int mCanvasHeight = 1;
    // private int mCanvasWidth = 1;

    private int mOffsetTop = 100;
    private int mOffsetLeft;



    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    private int iTo = 1;
    private int iFrom = 0;
    private String mSpeed = "normal";
    private int iTimes;

    private String mText; 
    private String receivedName;

    private final Runnable mDrawCube = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            drawFrame();
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    TextEngine() {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Geo-Regular.ttf");



        final Paint paint = mPaint;

        paint.setTextSize(18);
        paint.setTypeface(typeface);
        paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPrefs = ConsoleWallpaper.this.getSharedPreferences(
                SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        onSharedPreferenceChanged(mPrefs, null);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String key) {
        mSpeed = prefs.getString("speed", "normal");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        mVisible = visible;

        if (visible) {
            drawFrame();
        } else {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);



        // mCanvasWidth = width;
        mCanvasHeight = height;
        mPaint.setTextSize(width / 30);
        // mOffsetLeft = width / 30;
        mOffsetLeft = 0;
        drawFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        mVisible = false;



        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);


    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
            float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
        drawFrame();
    }


    public void drawFrame() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();



         c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {
                // draw something
                onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

        // Reschedule the next redraw
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
        if (mVisible) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawCube, 1000 / 25);
        }
    }

    void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.save();


        mText = receivedString";



        // draw
        String text = mText.substring(iFrom, iTo);
        String[] Strings = text.split("#");
        mPaint.setTextSize(40);
        for (int i = 0; i < Strings.length; i++) {
            c.drawText(Strings[i], mOffsetLeft, mOffsetTop, mPaint);
            mOffsetTop += mPaint.getTextSize();
            if (mOffsetTop > mCanvasHeight)
                reset(c);
        }
        iFrom = 0;
        mOffsetTop = 100;

        int t;
        if (mSpeed.equalsIgnoreCase("slow"))
            t = 5;
        else
            t = 1;

        if (iTimes % t == 0) {
            if (mSpeed.equalsIgnoreCase("fast"))
                iTo++;
            iTo++;
            iTimes = 0;
        }
        iTimes++;

        if (iTo > mText.length()) {
            iFrom = 0;
            iTo = 1;
            reset(c);
        }
        c.restore();
    }




    void reset(Canvas c) {
        mOffsetTop = 100;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
        c.drawPaint(paint);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Experts will be able to help if some of the code you have tried is posted along with the question.

Comment: Can't you pass a string to your `wallpaperservice`. Get the text from `EditText` and passed it into your service.

Comment: this is the main problem i don't know how can i pass it to extends WallpaperService, bundle methods kinda not working for me and still no text change is showing in the live wallpaper